# Dar hide ou show ao clicar em outro elemento

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho 4 tópicos, e gostaria de exibir apenas o que eu clicasse, e se outro estiver aberto fechar, eu sei fazer isso com jquery, mas eu estou fazendo de uma maneira que não acho a mais "correta", eu deixo o código muito extenso colocando muitas restrições e etc.

```
<a class="topico1">
<a class="topico2">
<a class="topico3">
<a class="topico4-exibir">
```

Eu gostaria de ao clicar em outro tópico ele ganhar o valor exibir e o que está com este valor atualmente perde-lo. Eu no caso faria uma função no click, que ao clicar na class topico3, verificar se ela tem a sub class exibir, se estiver remove a classe sub classe exibir de todas as outras, e se não tiver ela adiciona e remove de todas as outras, então no caso eu faria essa mesma função para todos as classes, isso leva muito tempo e código, teria como eu fazer de uma maneira mais facil? Espero que não tenha ficado muito complicado de entender.

Comment: Coloca o código de como você está fazendo com jQuery junto na pergunta, as vezes pode estar certo, só corrigir alguma coisa em cima ja fica bom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa de mais de 4 linhas pra fazer isso, adicione um classname em comum aos elementos, e faça isso.

```
$(document).on('click','.topic',function(){
    $('.topic').removeClass('exibir');
    $(this).addClass('exibir');
});
```

Exemplo funcional no fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5tof0rg/2/

Comment: Deu certo cara, muito obrigado. Era isso mesmo, eu no caso faria muitas verificações e restrições, assim da pra fazer em 4 linhas, valeu mesmo.